# How can I use avconv to convert multiple files in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, avconv

I'm new to Linux and I want to execute one command on every file in a loop:

```
avconv -i *.mp4 -vcodec copy -ac 2 -strict experimental *.mp4
```

Can any one tell me how I can do this? I have more than 100 files to convert. I just want to convert them into new files with the same names, but using different codecs. It works for one file but I don't know how to run it on all of the files. I found this [`avconv` documentation](http://libav.org/avconv.html) but I can't find the answer in there either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in *.mp4; do avconv -i "$i" -vcodec copy -ac 2 -strict experimental "out-$i"; done
```

Comment: In case of files with spaces, instances of `$i` usually need to be "quoted".

Comment: yes, you are right; corrected.

Comment: And it should be "out-$i" instead of "out-$i.mp4" unless you want to get files with *.mp4.mp4 extension ;)