# How to resize a picture for sharing (email, chat, social) in Ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone, bq, aquaris

I'm looking for a simple way to share pictures smaller than original size (taken by camera). Preferably multiple pictures and for practical reasons I'm looking for an App or setting, not a command line as this is on Ubuntu Touch phone Aquaris BQ.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Multiple pictures into one image or multiple pictures in batch resize?

Comment: Close voters. I for one think the question is fairly clear.

Comment: IIRC (not at an Ubuntu machine now) Shotwell's "Share..." menu has a resize option.

Comment: Just to clarify: Sharing single picture from original: x Mb to email size x Kb. Multiple meaning  more pictures at the same time (email for example).

Finally as my ubuntu touch rings on BQ phone, I don't see me typing in terminal to share a pic.

Android world has the same issue, I use to use "Image shrink (resizer) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.anolivetree This adds entry to "share menu" in each app, resizes and goes back to share menu from which you can actually share with apps. Anybody keen developing this? I'm happy to purchase support :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly I don't have access to a device like yours for testing purposes but
`avconv` has a good scaling filter.

`avconv -i BigInputimage.jpg -s 640x480 640x480smalloutput.jpg`

This should do the trick. For multiple files:

`for i in *.jpg; do avconv -i "$i" -s 640x480 "out-$i.jpg" ; done`

Where jpg is the extension of the images you wish to rescale.

multiple file command inspired by January answer regarding video here: [How can I use avconv to convert multiple files in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204649/how-can-i-use-avconv-to-convert-multiple-files-in-the-terminal)

Based on what little I could find it doesn't look like the Ubuntu touch gallery app supports resize as an edit option. If this is incorrect, 
please advise.

Since the [terminal](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2603686/opensource-subnet/how-the-terminal-made-ubuntu-touch-worth-using.html) is available now and it seems [cli tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269997/can-you-run-command-line-tools-on-ubuntu-touch) can be run on ubuntu touch. This seems a valid answer.

To follow the Ubuntu Touch core apps development, you may find this page of interest: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone-coreapps

Comment: Can none of the phone apps do it?

Comment: @muru I couldn't find anything that indicated that one way or the other.

Comment: That works on Ubuntu Touch?

Comment: @A.B.  It works on Ubuntu.

Comment: Clarification: My question was about ubuntu touch, yet I'm running it on the BQ phone. I just can't imagine for practical reasons typing this in terminal for sharing a picture.

Comment: @PavelPerina I'm sorry this wasn't the answer you wanted. I understood your question to be about resizing before sharing, not about sharing itself. If we've misunderstood your question, please [edit] it to provide more clarity. You may also wish to review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask - especially the final paragraph.

Comment: @ElderGeek Thank you for your suggestion, I have edited & clarified my question.

Comment: @PavelPerina I'm sorry the answer I provided doesn't fit your revised specifications. Hopefully someone else will chime in with a solution you are more comfortable implementing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageMagick:

e.g.

```
mogrify -path <output_path> -resize 60x60% -format png <your_pictures>/*.png
```

This will resize all images (png) in `<your_pictures_path>`

The smaller images are placed in `<output_path>`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using darktable or shutter, both i think that can be installed with

```
$ sudo apt-get install shutter darktable
```

Shutter provides you the easiest way to screenshot your desktop and edit it with the best simplicity ever.

Anyways if you want a photoshop ubuntu-user oriented you can install darktable, (if apt-get does not work, go to darktable website and please add their own repository and run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install darktables
```

Comment: Does it work on Ubuntu Touch?

Comment: I just did it worth in a Ubuntu Mate

Answer (score 0):

Over one year later since I have asked this question. It´s time to answer what I actually do to be able to use my Ubuntu Touch device for daily communication:

1. make sure the rotation lock is off
2. go to gallery find and view
       the picture to resize, rotate the screen to required orientation
3. make screenshot (up and down volume button at same time) you hear a
           sound
4. go to Gallery app the pictures are in time order, the latest screenshots are at the top.
5. share or email the resized picture

Yes, I´m aware this solution is a workaround, but this is what I  actually do. I find impractical to type long lines in terminal to share a picture and sharing 3Mb images is not cool anymore.

This is a call to developers, **please make simple resize app**!!! Thank you